# numpy's random vs python's default random subsampling

Tags: python, numpy, random, sample

I observed that python's default `random.sample` is much faster than numpy's `random.choice`. Taking a small sample from an array of length 1 million, `random.sample` is more than 1000x faster than its numpy's counterpart.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import random

In [3]: arr = [x for x in range(1000000)]

In [4]: nparr = np.array(arr)

In [5]: %timeit random.sample(arr, 5)
The slowest run took 5.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.54 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit np.random.choice(arr, 5)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.7 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit np.random.choice(nparr, 5)
The slowest run took 6.79 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.79 µs per loop
```

Although numpy sampling from numpy array was decently fast yet it was slower than default random sampling.

Is the observation above correct, or am I missing the difference between what `random.sample` and `np.random.choice` compute?

Comment: numpy seems to be faster (with `nparr`) when taking a larger sample than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing in your first call of `numpy.random.choice` is simply the overhead of converting the list `arr` to a numpy array.

As for your second call, the slightly worse is probably due to the fact that `numpy.random.choice` offers the ability to sample non-uniformly, and can also sample with replacement as well as without.